# Dynamically constructed knockout component template based on component params

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, components

I'm currently using knockout.js as part of an application I am developing. I have a need to implement a knockout component which contains an un-ordered list whose list items vary based on what the component params are.

The basic code for registering the component would be as follows:

```
ko.components.register('data-display', {
    viewModel: function(name, obj, vis) {
        var self = this;
        for (var index in obj) {
            self[index] = obj[index];
        }
    },
    template: //Template lives here
});

function templateConstructor(name, obj, vis) {
    var template = '<h2>' + name + '</h2>\r\n';
    template += '<ul>\r\n';
    for (var index in obj) {
        var kvInfo = getKVInfo(vis, index); 
        if (kvInfo) {
            template += '<li><strong>' + kvInfo + '</strong><span data-bind="text: ' + index + '"></span></li>\r\n';
        }
    }
    template += '</ul>\r\n';
    return template;
}

function getKVInfo(vis, index) {
    for(var key in vis) {
        if (key == index) {
            return vis[key];
        }
    }
    return False;
}
```

And the values of `obj`, `name` & `vis` would be of the form:

```
var name = "Information"
var obj = {foo: ko.observable('bar'), bar: ko.observable('foo'), ta: ko.observable('da')}
var vis = {foo: 'Foo Info: ', bar: 'Bar Info: '}
```

The idea is that the component would have a header containing name, then data displayed from obj being masked from vis. I.e: In the case above, only the `foo` and `bar` elements would be visible in the component.
The issue I am trying to solve is how to take the params from the HTML component declaration and pass them to the template as well as the view model, such that I could use the html:

```
<data-display params="name: name, obj: obj, vis: vis"></data-display>
```

And gain this result:

```
<h2>Information</h2>
<ul>
    <li><strong>Foo Info: </strong><span data-bind="text: foo"></span></li>
    <li><strong>Bar Info: </strong><span data-bind="text: bar"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in support for a component to have a dynamically created template. But a component can define a `createViewModel` property instead of a view model constructor, which will have access to the element. Here is an example:

```
ko.components.register('data-display', {
    viewModel: {
        createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
            var componentVM = new viewModelConstructor(params);
            var template = templateConstructor(componentVM);
            ko.virtualElements.setDomNodeChildren(componentInfo.element, ko.utils.parseHtmlFragment(template));
            return componentVM;
        }
    },
    template: []
});
```

Or you could use the generic component loader I've posted at https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1458#issuecomment-154578662

Comment: Worked like an absolute charm. Thanks for the assistance.